# capitalize first letter of a xml element

Tags: android, string, nodes, capitalization

I'm a newbie so please be patient.
I have the following code retrieving the nodes and its fine. I've attempted to get the 'status' node to have it's first letter capitalized with little success, it force closes.

What I've done is convert the element to a string. I figured out that I could use the capitalization code for all the elements 'e' but I'd rather use it for status. 
Why is it forcing close?
Could someone please help me with this?

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("line");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);

        map.put("id", XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
        map.put("name", XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
        map.put("status", XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "status"));
        map.put("message", XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "message"));

        mylist.add(map);

//element to string
        Document document = e.getOwnerDocument();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document
            .getImplementation();
        LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        String str = serializer.writeToString(e);

//capitalization
        if (str.length() <= 1) {
            str = str.toLowerCase();
        } else {
            str = str.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + str.substring(1);
        }
```

Comment: if you paste your error log/stacktrace would be better.

Comment: 04-01 22:32:34.928: W/dalvikvm(5306): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
04-01 22:32:34.928: E/AndroidRuntime(5306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 22:32:34.928: E/AndroidRuntime(5306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{augment.reality.app/augment.reality.app.Service}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DOMImplementationImpl

Comment: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
 ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1659 
 ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1675 
 ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 121 
 ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 943 
 ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
 Looper.loop() line: 130 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3701

Comment: If you delete the capitalization part and just show the string in toast, does the application run?

Comment: Hope so you had solve your issues?

Comment: @HeshamSaeed nope, forces close still when trying to display string as toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the following code:

```
public static String getValue(Element item, String str)  {      


        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);

              char[] chars = XMLFunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0)).toLowerCase().toCharArray();
              boolean found = false;
              for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                if (!found && Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
                  chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
                  found = true;
                } else if (Character.isWhitespace(chars[i]) || chars[i]=='.' || chars[i]=='\'') { // You can add other chars here
                  found = false;
                }
              }

              return String.valueOf(chars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
str = str.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase().concat(str.substring(1));
```